# An integer equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I need to prove the following interesting result: given $a,c,d\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$, where $a\nmid c$ and $c\neq d$, then the following statement is not true: for any $k_1,k_2\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ there exists $n \in\mathbb{N}^{+}$
such that $k_1c+k_2d=na$

Comment: It's false. For example, $c=6$, $d=10$, $a=4$; then  $c+d$ is a multiple of $a$.

Comment: @rogerl I have a feeling that you have misunderstood the question. The statement we are trying to prove false is that for any choice of $k_1, k_2$ we can find such $n$.

Comment: Ok, I may explain the question carefully

Answer (score 1):

Let $k_1 = 1, k_2= a.$ Then surely there doesn't exist such $n$.

Comment: Or take $k_1=1, k_2$ and $k_1=1, k_2+1$. Subtract them.